# Is there any way to use Safari 5.1's rendering engine for browser testing on OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, safari

I have OSX 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion) on both my Macs, which comes with Safari 6.1. A couple of my clients have been reporting minor CSS errors using Safari 5.1, which I obviously can't install. This makes fixing these errors very, very difficult.

Are there any recommended methods for testing with the rendering engines of older versions of Safari? Would there be an appropriate vintage version of Webkit that would be able to install on 10.8, as the appropriate nightlies refuse to run?

Comment: I've found the excellent http://www.browserstack.com/ which was indispensable for the time being. A native solution would, of course, be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a project online which i think uses an old WEBKIT renderer..
http://michelf.ca/projects/multi-safari/ gives old versions, but i don't know which ones you will be able to run on your new machine. For myself,  I'm running 4.0.5 because of the reduced RAM usage.

Answer (score -2):

The latest version of Safari Web Browser is 6.0.5. *Your clients **should** be using the latest version.* But for you to test on older versions, **go into Boot Camp Assistant and install an older version of OS X** (using the Disks that came with your Mac). I have Lion and Tiger on this MacBook I am posting this answer on. Boot into Tiger and try to replicate the problem. Make sure not to update Safari on that OS.

Answer (score -5):

You can enable the **Develop menu** in the **Preferences > Advanced** checkbox (show develop menu in the menubar).

Once you do that, you can change the user agent to the older versions of Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just changes the User Agent, which is what the browser reports is it's name. This is very useful when testing websites that rely on this, but I don't want to do this. I want to use the rendering engine from Safari 5.1, to help debug a CSS error. I'll update the question to clarify.